# Laravel delete item from table list / db

Tags: php, laravel, crud, laravel-blade, laravel-5.4

I am trying to delete item from a generated table of items which are from a database table.

My Route:

```
Route::delete('destroy/{deviceID}', ['as' => 'destroyDevice', 'uses' => 'DeviceController@destroyDevice']);
```

My Controller method to delete an item:

```
public function destroyDevice(Request $request, $deviceId = 0)
{
    $device = Device::find($deviceId);

    if($device)
    {
        $device->delete();
        return redirect()->route('index')->with('success', 'Erfolgreich gelöscht');
    }
    else
    {
        return redirect()->route('index')->with('error', 'Fehler');
    }
}
```

And my blade template:

```
                <form action="{{ route('destroyDevice', $deviceValue->id) }}" method="post" name="delete_device">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $deviceValue->id }}">
                    <td>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="destroy_device">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </form>
```

If I click on the button nothing happens no error no Response, what am I doing wrong.

If I click on the third delete button the form holds this:

```
<form action="http://localhost/app/public/device/destroy/3" method="post" name="delete_device"></form>
```

Comment: When you click on the button, do you see a request send to the server in the web console ?

Comment: The console does not Show anything if I click on the button

Comment: @EkinOf I posted the whole blade

Comment: Could you post your route binding for `{deviceID}`?

Comment: @MarijkeLuttekes Hmm what excatly do you mean, I posted the Action URL if that helps

Comment: Route model binding is the mapping in your route files that tells the app what the value of `{deviceID}` should correspond to. See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-model-binding

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by putting the form inside a td tag in that table.

Like this:

```
  <td> <!--  <--- put these -->
      <form action="{{ route('destroyDevice', $deviceValue->id) }}" method="post" name="delete_device">
          <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">
          <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
          <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $deviceValue->id }}">

              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="destroy_device">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
              </button>

      </form>
  </td> <!--  <--- put these -->
```

I think the form gets ignored somehow due to not being valid, but I am not 100% sure. May people edit this answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

The parameter is case sensitive so it should be **deviceID** instead of **deviceId**

```
public function destroyDevice(Request $request, $deviceID = 0)
```

Comment: try `public function destroyDevice(Request $request, $deviceId)`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have some script that prevents the form to submit, some prevent default maybe on button click or on form submit. Check that.